# Python try/finally wtih sys.exc_info()

Tags: python, exception, logging

I'm trying to write a python job that which I will be using in all the other jobs to capture the job start time and when a program finishes successfully or with some issues, I capture the error details and load the details into a table.

```
job_status

def srt(jobname):
   sts = 'running'
   df_srt = select(f'''select /'{job_name}/' as job_name, /'{strt_time}/' as strt_time, /'{sts}/' as sts''')
   df_srt.write.to_csv(/path_name)

def end(jobname):
   df_end = select(f'''select /'{job_name}/' as job_name, /'{strt_time}/' as strt_time, /'{end_time}/', /'{log}/' as log, /'{sts}/' as sts ''')
   df_end.write.to_csv(/path_name)
```

Program I'm using the job

```
from job_status import *

    def main_program:
       try:
          # some operation
          print(1/0)
       except:
         pass
       finally:
          if sys.exc_info()[0] is not None:
                status = 'Failed'
                log = concat(sys.exc_info()[0],' , ', sys.exc_info()[1], ' , ', sys.exc_info()[2])
                end_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                end(job_name=__name__, strt_time=start_time, end_time=end_time, sts=sts, log=log)
            else:
                sts = 'Success'
                end_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                end(job_name=__name__, start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time, status=status)
```

I'm trying to capture the error details, whenever a issue happens. But regardless the nature of the error, sys.exc_info()[0] goes to the success path. Any idea, How I can implement this?

Comment: Be aware of creating GC cycles between exceptions and frames.

Comment: @o11c I have tried to do some research on this, But not able to get any solid information. Can you tell what problem I might encounter with the "GC cycles between exceptions and frames"?

Comment: Description of the problem: https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-dev/146458 Documentation of the objects: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects Also relevant: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/ https://bugs.python.org/issue31005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Note: A comment indicates that the code in the OP was not intended to catch an exception; rather, the intent was to just log the success or failure, and let the original exception propagate. The code here has been modified to accomplish that.*)

The `try` command includes three types of additional clauses: `except`, `else` and `finally`:

- `"except" [expression ["as" identifier]]`

  If an expression is provided, the clause is executed if an exception is thrown which matches the expression. If no expression is provided, the clause is executed if any exception is thrown.
- `else`

  If no exception is thrown, the clause is executed.
- `finally`

  The clause is executed at the end of the `try` block, after any matching `except` or `else` clause.

(See [Note 1] for the precise syntax. See the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) for more details.)

`sys.exc_info` can be used *in an `except` clause* (or in a function called during execution of an `except` clause) to extract information about the exception. Once the `except` clause finishes, `sys.exc_info` no longer returns useful information. Since the `finally` clause executes after the `except` clause has finished, that's the case in your code.

But what you are trying to do with `if exc_info is not None:` is exactly what the `try` statement's `else` clause does anyway. So you could have written your code somewhat more simply using an `else` clause. I did a little refactoring in order to be able to put common code in a `finally` clause.

In order to propagate the exception, it's necessary to finish the `except` clause with a `raise` statement without an expression. This will cause the exception to continue "as though it were raised by the `try` block". However, the `finally` clause is still executed before propagating.

```py
def main_program:
    start_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    try:
        # some operation
        print(1/0)
    except:
        status = 'Failed'
        log = concat(sys.exc_info()[0],' , ', sys.exc_info()[1], ' , ', sys.exc_info()[2])
        raise
    else:
        status = 'Success'
        log = None
    finally:
        end_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        end(job_name=__name__, start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time, sts=sts, log=log)
```

#### Notes:

1. The precise grammar of the `try` statement shows that you must have either at least one `except` clause or a `finally` clause, and that you can only have an `else` clause if you have an `except` clause. From the docs:

   ```
   try_stmt  ::=  try1_stmt | try2_stmt
   try1_stmt ::=  "try" ":" suite
                  ("except" [expression ["as" identifier]] ":" suite)+
                  ["else" ":" suite]
                  ["finally" ":" suite]
   try2_stmt ::=  "try" ":" suite
                  "finally" ":" suite
   ```
2. I don't know what `concat` is supposed to do here, so I just left it as is. It cannot be a simple string concatenation since the components of the tuple returned by `sys.exc_info` aren't strings, and if that's what you were looking for `', '.join(map(str, exc_info()))` would work. If it's some function which does nice formatting of the object returned by `sys.exc_info`, then you might consider just passing it the object returned by `sys.exc_info`.

Comment: Thanks, One very important functionality in my job is, I want to capture all these error messages and log them and I still want to let the job to fail. Because these jobs are being run by a scheduler, if one of the job fails the whole workflow has to be stopped.

Comment: @user7343922: That requirement is not clear from your question, so you should probably add it to the question. Your code does not satisfy that requirement either because once you catch an exception, it's been caught; `except: pass` means that the exception will not be passed through. If you want to pass the exception through, that will require a slight modification to my code.

Comment: The structure works, But when I try to capture the error message, like this "    except:
        status = 'Failed'
        log = ''.join(traceback.format_stack())", I'm not getting the "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero" and the line number. What am I doing wrong? I'm just getting the calling program name (I'm calling this program using a driver) and this message "log = .join(traceback.format_stack())"

Comment: @user7343922: `log = ".join(...)"` sets `log` to a string constant; it doesn't execute anything. What I think you're looking for is `log = '\n'.join(traceback.format_stack())`; except that  you  probably want more information from the exception.

Comment: Yes, But, Can you please suggest me how can I get that more or all the information about the error messages?

Comment: @user7343922: All the information is in the error object returned by `sys.exc_info`. IMHO, formatting that information nicely is well outside of the scope of this question, which was about how to observe success or failure of a block of code.

Comment: But probably the easiest is `log = traceback.format_exc()`. That will give you a single string (so no need for `join`) containing the traceback and the exception message.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.exc_info()` contains information for the exception *that is currently being handled*.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) (emphasis mine):

> This function returns a tuple of three values that give information about the exception that is currently being handled. [...] If the current stack frame is not handling an exception, the information is taken from the calling stack frame, or its caller, and so on until a stack frame is found that is handling an exception. **Here, “handling an exception” is defined as “executing an except clause.”** For any stack frame, only information about the exception being currently handled is accessible. If no exception is being handled anywhere on the stack, a tuple containing three `None` values is returned.

Inside of a `finally` clause, you are already *past* the point of handling an exception.  So instead, you will need to save off the relevant information about the exception from *inside* of the `except` clause.  For example:

```
exc_info = None
try:
    # some operation
    print(1/0)
except:
    exc_info = sys.exc_info()
finally:
    if exc_info is not None:
        status = 'Failed'
        # ...
    else:
        status = 'Success'
        # ...
```

Comment: If I move the code block in "finallly" to "except", then I will be capturing the status and logs only if there is an exception, isn't it?. But, I want to record the status and logs even when the job runs successfully. Any suggestion on How I can do that?

Comment: @user7343922 There are a number of ways you could structure it - see my edit for one example.

Comment: the structure works, But, I'm not able to properly capture the sys.exc_info messages. I tried to "str(sys.exc_info()[0])", It's not working. And also one important, It may be a weird request, How can I still let the job to still fail, even after capturing all the error messages. Because, all these files are being run by a scheduler, If a job fails, the whole work flow has to be stopped. I just want to capture the error messages and let the job to fail.